# Proper Implementation of Multi Tenancy in Node Application

Tags: mysql, node.js, multi-tenant, saas

I currently have to decide how to implement multi tenancy with my node application the best way possible. 
For now, I have got my common_db_connection where I have a lookup table in which I can query the tenant database name for each specific user.

I have a resolver function which uses the users ID to get the tenant database name and finally return the my mysql connector.

My solution looks like this:

```
var conn_common_db  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 150,
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'common_db'
});

function conn_resolver(req) {

    conn_common_db.query("SELECT tenant_db_name from tenants where tenant_uid = (SELECT tenant_uid from tenant_user where user_uid = ?)",
     [requst.session.user_uid], function(err, result) {

        if(!err) {
            tenant_db_name = result[0].tenant_db_name

            return mysql.createPool({
                connectionLimit : 150,
                host     : 'localhost',
                user     : 'root',
                password : '',
                database : tenant_db_name
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log(err)
            return null;
        }
    })
}

app.get('/', function(request, response) {

    conn_resolver(req).query("SELECT *  FROM user", function(err, result) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log(result)
        }
        else{
            //res.send(err)
        }
    })

});
```

Is this the right way to do this and is it safe to do it like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMHO, As one of the ways to implement multi-tenancy it is fine

Answer (score 0):

Actually no. You either need to set up a pool per tenant or just a singular connection each time.

The concept of a pool is to have a reusable connection that is already connected to the database. The next tenant will be connected to the wrong database. So you will have to recreate the pool as each tenant tries to connect to their database. You could create a pool per tenant or just do a connection on the fly.